# Call JavaScript function in AbstractJavaScriptExtension class

Tags: javascript, jquery, vaadin

I would like to call javascript function in vaadin. Its a `AbstractJavaScriptExtension`.
`this.callFunction("removeNode");` does not fire the javascript function. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
@Override
public void remove() {
    super.remove();
    fireRemoveNode();
    this.callFunction("removeNode");
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
window.vaadin_components_graph_Node = function() {
        var self = this;
        var state = this.getState();
```

...

```
        this.removeNode = function() {
            console.log("CALL FUNCTION", "remove node")
            $(node).remove();
        }
};
```

Comment: at first glance, this all looks correct. the component in general is working (aka: there are no deeper problems)?  also to have it said: you are aware, that the server will not call this function on it's own on the client without the context of a request (or push enabled maybe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call JavaScript functions after the AbstractJavaScriptExtension is removed. Try placing this JavaScript call to another method and don't call remove();

Answer (score 0):

While user1411778 answer is correct, you can also call JavaScript function using:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("removeNode()");
```

It should work always.